# random phrase of random words using arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, variables

I'm trying to make a random phrase generator, which is made of random words. 
I have some arrays with words and some with sentences.

Here's the code:

```
noun = ['noun1','noun2','noun3'...]
@noun = noun.shuffle.sample

verb = ['verb1','verb2','verb3']
@verb = verb.shuffle.sample 

... # here are some more words

phrase = [['@noun','@verb'...],['@verb', '@noun'...],[...] ...] # here're some phrases
@phrase = phrase.shuffle.sample
```

Here's the verb-fragment: `<%= @phrase %>`

The output isn't rendering array elements, just their names:

```
["@noun", "@verb", ...]
```

Comment: It does not make sense to `shuffle` before `sample`. It is redundant.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using single quotes. Try this instead:

```
phrase = [[@noun, @verb...]
```

What you were doing was outputting a string rather than the variable. Have a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_strings.htm) to find out more about strings and how to use them.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it seems obviuos...

Comment: would you like to accept this answer? :)

Comment: Yes, thank you again. Now things work well.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the quotes in the `phrase` line:

```
phrase = [[@noun,@verb], [@verb, @noun]]
```

Because you want to have an array with the values from the variables `@noun` and `@verb`, and not an array with strings containing the words '@noun' and '@verb'